# How to use principal components in R to apply a multinomial logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, pca

Context: I have an original dataset of +- 20k rows (samples) and 253 features (deletions, insertions and substitutions). These columns/dimensions/features are called SNVs (single nucleotide variants from different SARS-CoV-2 strains).

After adjusting some of the variables, I was left with +- 19k samples and 19 variables (insertions, deletions and substitutions). The 1st variable is the "clade"(groups such as Delta, Omicron variants, etc) :

```
1   19A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
2   20B 4   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   
3   20A 4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   
4   20B 4   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   
5   20A 4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I've used the library `factoextra` and `factominer` to apply the PCA and I've gotten these results:

A matrix with this output:

```
              Dim.1         Dim.2         Dim.3         Dim.4         Dim.5
1      0.8093387170 -6.3198529745 -1.0274428559 -9.027631e-02  0.4655408780
2      0.7784308534 -5.2043922005 -0.1307601776  2.086402e-01 -1.1093766380
3      0.5896404096 -5.7720340307 -0.9180944507 -6.990509e-02  0.6177750772
4      0.7784308534 -5.2043922005 -0.1307601776  2.086402e-01 -1.1093766380
5      0.5896404096 -5.7720340307 -0.9180944507 -6.990509e-02  0.6177750772
6      0.5896404096 -5.7720340308 -0.9180944507 -6.990509e-02  0.6177750772
7      0.4240139051 -5.3435222802 -0.5281714944  7.112027e-02 -0.1740873901
8      0.5896404096 -5.7720340308 -0.9180944507 -6.990509e-02  0.6177750772
9      0.6148153756 -5.4065982562 -0.7704924684 -1.560130e-01  0.6866722240
10     0.9721157126 -5.0066038782 -0.2534396294  2.053737e-01 -1.0174806249
....
```

Where Dim.1 and Dim.2 explain +- 71% of the original dataset.

```
       eigenvalue  variance.percent  cumulative.variance.percent
Dim.1   8.48612871  44.6638353  44.66384
Dim.2   5.01077343  26.3724917  71.03633
Dim.3   1.14491619  6.0258747   77.06220
Dim.4   1.01265807  5.3297793   82.39198
Dim.5   0.65772735  3.4617229   85.85370...
```

And I got this graph:

[image: PCA graph]

I'd now like to apply a `Multinomial logistic regression`. The goal is to pass a specific sequence to this logistic regression model and predict the SARS-CoV-2 variant/strain. How could I train this model using the results from 2 or 3 principal components (the first 3 dimensions, for example) from the `factoextra` package? I was trying to use the `multinom` in R, but I'm not sure how I could pass the dimensions and split them into training and testing data

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Please do not make a new account and post the same question on a different Stack.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/558358/247274) I stand by my comment on Cross Validated. PCA ignores the $y$ variable.